# Synonym for 'reduced packaging'

Tags: synonyms

Is there a one-word synonym for the bulky description of a product that is "packaged using reduced packaging"? So that one could use the synonym in a sentence like, "This product is xxxx"? I used "reduced packaged" but I am not sure if that's correct.

Comment: **sustainable packaging** https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sustainable_packaging

Comment: Sustainable packaging and resource friendly packaging is a very general, "umbrella" term that covers all type of packaging including biodegradable, recyclable, made of recycled materials, reduced-packaged products.

Comment: Then please expand your question to be more specific. :)

Comment: What does "reduced packaging" mean?  It sounds as if it means there is less packaging than usual - but that's not consistent with something being *made of reduced packaging*.  Or do you mean it's made of recycled packaging?

Comment: My bad, Trevor - I mean that the package is now using less material.

Comment: "Broken champagne glasses, now with less packaging!"

Comment: @Olga But in the Q. you said "a ... product that is ***made of*** reduced packaging".  And now you seem to be asking about the packaging ***around*** the product?!

Comment: Hi Trevor - I think that they essentially mean the same thing.The product that contains less packaging is essentially made of reduced packaging.

Comment: To give you more context, this is the phrase that I am trying to improve. Among sustainably packaged products, are ***reduced-package***  more operationally efficient than ***non-reduced-package***?

Comment: @Olga They *do not* mean the same thing. To take an extreme example, a computer cannot be *made of* 'packaging' (reduced or otherwise), but it is sold in a box, usually with some 'padding' around it. The box & the internal padding are the 'packaging' (which may or may not be 'reduced'): the 'product' is the computer.  I read your Q as being about products that are actually *manufactured from recycled packaging*.

Comment: @Olga Additionally, your second comment contradicts your first comment: in referring to "packaged products", you are clearly distinguishing between the 'packaging' & the 'product' - the 'product' is what is inside the 'packaging'.

Comment: @Olga I've taken the liberty of amending your Q. to make it clear that it is only the packaging being referred to - not the product inside the package. If you're not happy with my amendment, please feel free to change it.

Answer (score 1):

*"This product is sustainably packaged"*

**Sustainable Packaging** — [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sustainable_packaging)

> Sustainable packaging is the development and use of packaging which results in improved sustainability.
>
> This involves increased use of life cycle inventory (LCI) and life cycle assessment (LCA) to help guide the use of packaging which reduces the environmental impact and ecological footprint.
>
> It includes a look at the whole of the supply chain: from basic function, to marketing, and then through to end of life (LCA) and rebirth. Additionally, an eco-cost to value ratio can be useful
>
> The goals are to improve the long term viability and quality of life for humans and the longevity of natural ecosystems.

Comment: Sustainable packaging and resource friendly packaging is a very general, "umbrella" term that covers all type of packaging including biodegradable, recyclable, made of recycled materials, reduced-packaged products. I was looking for something that is specifically **reduced**, so a person has no doubts about its meaning.

Comment: @Olga then how about **minimally packaged**? Googling that will give you many examples.

Comment: Thanks NVZ, I see what you are saying. Do you think that one can use the term "reduced-packaged"? Or does it sound awkward?

Comment: @Olga Worth checking out: http://www.thedieline.com/blog/2015/1/13/4-emerging-package-design-trends-of-2015

Comment: @Olga Saying "this product is *reduced-packaged*" sounds odd. Use *packaged minimally* instead. I think you should search about "minimalistic packaging"

Comment: @NVZ and Olga You would refer to the product as, "This product "has" minimal packaging." You might also say that, "The product comes with minimal packaging."

Answer (score 1):

<sup>*Posting another answer, based on discussion in comments.*</sup>

If minimum amount of material is used for its packaging,
*"product has **minimal packaging**"*,
*"product is **minimally packaged**"*

**Minimum** — [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/minimal)

> *noun* the lowest number or amount that is possible or allowed

Or, if it follows the currently trending design philosophy called "minimalism",
*"product has **minimalist packaging**"*,
*"product is **minimalistically packaged**"*

**Minimalism** — [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/minimalism)

> *noun* a style or technique (as in music, literature, or design) that is characterized by extreme spareness and simplicity

Read more on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimalism). <sub><sup>(emphasis mine)</sup></sub>

> The concept of minimalist architecture is to strip everything down to its essential quality and achieve simplicity. The idea is not completely without ornamentation, but that all parts, details and joinery are considered as **reduced to a stage where no one can remove anything further to improve the design**.